# If I just keep decreasing the resistance of the wire between the load and the battery, does that mean that the current flow is increased?

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, resistance, current-limiting

If I keep decreasing the resistance of the wire connecting the load and the battery, will the current flow increase, until the maximum current level the specific battery can give is reached?
If so, and I want to supply 12 amps of electric current, using a 6Ah battery with 24 volts, and a c rating of 2, then would I just need to add a wire that has a resistance of 2ohms?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?  What device will be connected to the battery?  You are asking about what you think is the solution to your problem without revealing the problem.  Maybe there's a better solution - or maybe there isn't even a problem there to begin with.

Comment: some loads have current limiting features and or safety devices such as fuses.  Not all resistors are the same.  if you exceed the wattage capabilities of the resistor, you may see your assumption of the resistance value fail.

Comment: @JRE You're right, I should clearly mention the problem, which I haven't. I will make sure to clearly post a new question with the problem.

Comment: @SreenandanBalasubramaniam:  You can edit either (or both) of your existing questions to make them clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"connecting the load and the battery" ... uh ... usually the load determines the current. As long as the wire has much less resistance than the load, decreasing the wire's resistance any further has minimal effect.

Now there's nothing wrong with your 2 ohm example as long as you understand that the wire itself IS the load ... as in an electric heater.

More generally, the current is determined by the battery voltage and the sum of three separate resistances:

1. the battery's internal resistance
2. the load resistance
3. And the resistance of the wiring.

To use a battery efficiently, you want the load to be the main part of this sum, and the wiring resistance and the battery internal resistance to be a small percentage or ideally 0..

The way you have worded the question makes it unclear if you understand this, or if you are actually asking something else.

Comment: So the current is = voltage/(the battery's internal resistance + the load resistance + the wiring's resistance)

Answer (score 0):

> If I keep decreasing the resistance of the wire connecting the load and the battery, will the current flow increase,

Yes

> until the maximum current level the specific battery can give is reached?

There's not any limiting mechanism in the battery to limit current. At least not in a simple battery. 'Protected' lithium batteries have extra circuitry that may perform this function. Simple batteries will just keep on supplying more current as a decreasing load resistance demands it.

> If so, and I want to supply 12 amps of electric current, using a 6Ah battery with 24 volts, and a C rating of 2, then would I just need to add a wire that has a resistance of 2ohms?

A C rating of 2 means it should safely supply 2*6 = 12 amps. However, you would expect the battery to have some internal resistance, so when delivering 12 A, the terminal voltage will be a little less than 24 V. The wire resistance will then need to be a little less than 2 ohms.

If you reduce the wire resistance below this, you would expect the battery current to increase further. The 2C rating is not the maximum it can deliver, it's the maximum it can deliver safely, or while meeting some other specification. Above its C rating, you should not be surprised if the battery gets hot or damaged, or has its cycle lifetime reduced.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> If I keep decreasing the resistance of the wire connecting the load and the battery, will the current flow increase, until the maximum current level the specific battery can give is reached?

That depends on the characteristics of the load.  For a load that is mostly resistive, like a light bulb, the load current is proportional to the voltage applied *at the load*, as defined in Ohm's Law.

However, many solid state circuits, such as opamps, some audio power amplifiers, and some LED power supplies, have circuit techniques that ignore variations in the applied voltage.  This is how an audio circuit ignores, or "rejects" hum on its power supply lines.  In both cases, the load current is relatively constant despite changes in the supply voltage (over a limited range).  In all cases, it is the load that determines how much current is drawn from the battery as its voltage, and the voltage drop in the connecting wires, varies; in the first case it can vary a lot, and in others very little.

In almost all cases, it is bad practice to depend on the wiring to regulate the system power.  In terms of circuit performance, you want the wiring to be invisible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please explain what you mean by "In terms of circuit performance, you want the wiring to be invisible"?